# Sequence do ID avança +1 durante erro [PostgreSQL]

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, tabela-banco-de-dados, chave-primária, restrição-único

Tenho a seguinte tabela no banco de dados em postgreSQL

[image: Tabela de cargos]

O fato é que a coluna **Descrição** é *unique_key* então por questões testes eu resolvi inserir alguns registros com os valores repetidos na coluna descrição para verificar se estava funcionando bem, o problema é que mesmo quando ocorre o erro de integridade ele não dá um "*rollback*" na sequencia do ID e continua contando, ou seja, o 3º registro da minha tabela eu induzi o erro 6 vezes e mesmo assim ele continua incrementando o ID quando na verdade ele deveria ir para o 3, alguém saberia como corrigir isso?

Comment: Respondi sua pergunta sobre o porque disso ocorrer, mas seria interessante você explicar se seu cenário exige, de fato, que os identities sejam não só sequenciais, mas também contíguos, para que posso comentar com alternativas na resposta.

Comment: Meu cenário é que está é um tabela de um banco de dados no qual é implementada por um metodo de um software do qual estou construindo em c# winforms, a coluna correspondente ao *Código* é a chave primária. A principio me preocupei com esse fator apenas por estética do cadastro dos registros no gridView mas depois eu fiquei pensando que poderia vir a ser um problema caso esses saltos absurdos de um valor para o outro pudessem vir a diminuir o desempenho do software visto que algumas tabela como essa por exemplo o ID é um *smallserial*

Comment: Para não se preocupar com esse campo, aumente-o para o tipo de maior valor possível serial. Em todos os meus bancos de dados, como não posso prever o tamanho de dados antes do lançamento do sistema, costumo usar `bigserial`. Isso não diminuirá o desempenho do software, apenas usará alguns bytes a mais por registro e no índice. Esse impacto é totalmente negligível hoje em dia. Lembre-se: espaço em disco (e na nuvem) é barato, hora de programação e manutenção é bem mais caro :-)

Comment: acho que uma boa solução paliativa para seu problema seria realizar a verificação de duplicidade antes de inserir no banco de dados. Isso é interessante de qualquer maneira, pois você pode adicionar mensagens de erro mais amigáveis ao usuário do que erros de restrições de banco de dados. Contudo, lembre-se que se houver acessos paralelos, não é garantido que por ter testado a inserção imediatamente antes de enviar o "insert" não tenha havido outro insert no meio do caminho justamente com o valor duplicado! Mas já diminui bastante a chance de saltos de id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A geração da sequência é/precisa ser independente da transação. A ideia é que ela mantenha, sempre, um valor único, crescente: estão em sequência mas não é garantido que sejam contíguos.

Imagine um cenário onde você abra uma transação, insira 1000 registros, ao mesmo tempo outro usuário do banco insere 100 registros sem qualquer transação. Os ids gerados dentro da transação e fora dela não podem ser iguais, é preciso que sejam únicos. Seria impossível para o banco de dados resolver essa questão sem travar as inserções em outras transações e isso seria desastroso para qualquer tipo de banco de dados: detonaria com a performance.

Caso você tente implementar esse sequencial por si mesmo, leve em consideração esse mesmo problema de acessos paralelos, pois uma implementação ingênua vai parecer funcionar para cenários de acesso em série e único, mas falhará tragicamente para cenários de acesso paralelo, que são os cenários mais comuns de uso de um banco de dados.

O sequencial é também determinado antes de se aplicar a integridade referencial, pois os dados completos da linha sendo inserida precisam estar disponíveis para realizar essa verificação, e a primary key da mesma é necessária. Pelos mesmos motivos da independência da transação, não é possível parar as demais rotinas de inserção até que se determine uma falha de integridade referencial (no caso nem é integridade referencial, mas sim uma falha de índice com restrição única). Lembre-se que índices e "*constraints*" não são dados intrínsecos de uma tabela, e podem ser removidos e adicionados sem mudar a estrutura. Por uma questão de performance, escalonamento e simplicidade de implementação o valor dos *identities* são gerados antes de se inserir de fato a linha, e isso ocorre antes da validação da mesma, portanto não é possível "retornar" o valor do sequencial *a posteriori*. Por esse motivo, após o erro, um ou outro identity será "pulado".

Você não precisa se preocupar com isso em 99,999999% dos cenários. Exigir que sejam contíguos é, via de regra, desnecessário. Também não é boa prática de desenvolvimento se fiar na lógica de geração dos identities de um banco de dados, pois a mesma pode mudar com a versão do banco. Use os identities tão somente como o identificador único do registro que são. Eles podem também servir para ordenar os dados pela ordem de inserção no banco (lembre-se que essa ordem pode ser misturada entre várias inserções e transações paralelas).

Se você está preocupado com o desperdício dos identities pulados pode deixar de se preocupar, isso nunca (ou praticamente nunca) virá a prejudicá-lo.

Comment: Ok obrigado, vou fechar o tópico!